# How to compile the Arduino bootloader?

Tags: bootloader, atmega

I am using Arduino atmega328P (3.3v,8Mhz) for my project. As my application requirement I need to change the bootloader.

I have found one related link which is useful for me: http://www.rotwang.co.uk/projects/bootloader.html

Now I want to compile this bootloader in my system running on Windows 10 through command prompt.

I've tried a lot but was not able to compile the bootloader. It gives me a error like "The system cannot find the path specified". I've tried a lot to solve this problem but unfortunately I was not successful.

So can anyone tell me step by step what I should do to solve it. Do I need to change anything?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the enviroment variable to compile the bootloader. Here I'm using one for **C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin** e one for **c:\SysGCC\Raspberry\bin**

The first one cames with Arduino IDE, the second it's from Raspberry crosscompiler toolchain (http://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/). Both easy to find.

Try google *WINDOWS PATH VARIABLE* to permanently change your enviroment.

After that you just cmd (into your bootloader's folder) for **make.exe "board"**.

eg: **c:\SysGCC\Raspberry\bin\make.exe diecimila_14** (this one is for my 14MHz arduino board). You might see a new file in your atmega bootloader folder:

**C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\bootloaders\atmega\ATmegaBOOT_168_diecimila14mhz.hex**

I have a bat file to temporary change the PATH VARIABLE, you could try it

```
@echo off
REM set PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\bin\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\bin
set PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin
c:\SysGCC\Raspberry\bin\make.exe diecimila_14
```

BR from Brazil.

Answer (score 0):

The link you have mentioned refers further to the Git repository of the project of the bootloader. And the very description of the project gives the steps to build it:

> Production builds of optiboot for Arduino are done on a Mac in "unix
>   mode" using CrossPack-AVR-20100115.  CrossPack tracks WINAVR (for
>   windows), which is just a package of avr-gcc and related utilities, so
>   similar builds should work on Windows or Linux systems

Follow these to get the bootloader built: [Optiboot small bootloader for AVR](https://github.com/DaveBerkeley/arduino/tree/master/boot/optiboot)